# Database column naming

Tags: database, naming-conventions

Let's suppose there is a table called AIRPORT and I have to choose between two naming conventions:

- to name attributes like AP_CODE, AP_NAME and so on
- or to name them just like CODE, NAME

The question is whether it is more *efficient* to follow the first way or to use synonym (i.e. AP) and reference attributes like AP.CODE?

Answer (score 2):

It's not likely to have any significant performance impact either way in any RBDMS in common use. The choice would be based on readability and personal style preference. I would advise against the prefixing as it's usually just noise that people train themselves to tune out anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's really no difference, so opt for clarity.  I've recently been using Oracle, which has something like a 32 character name length limit, so I try to avoid the table name prefix on attributes and instead use the table aliases.  (This also makes it a bit easier to change your table names.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use CODE and NAME. Personally, I think it's simply clumsy and adds no benefit at all.

If you have have CODE and NAME in other tables, then you'd have to specify `AIRPORT.CODE` and `OTHERTABLE.CODE` to remove ambiguity

If you use `WITH SCHEMABINDING` (SQL server at least) you have to qualify column names

So, you'd end up with `AIRPORT.AP_CODE` if you used column prefixes

As an analogy if you think about an OO object properties, you don't prefix them, do you...?

To answer exactly, there is absolutely no efficiency gain.